# What does 'els' mean?

Tags: integration, differential

What would you understand by the term 'els' used in. $$B_1, B_2 \textrm{ els} Q(z).$$ The context is differential algebra and the Risch integration algorithm. My best guess is 'elementary elements of' but it's not clear in his 1969 paper. Found here: http://www.cs.ru.nl/~freek/courses/mfocs-2012/risch/1995313.pdf

Thanks

Comment: It's a rather extended short writing for elements, but it also is a pretty rude and ugly thing to use without properly warning potential readers...

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: I thought this but the author of the paper I have seen this in uses both $\in$ and els which suggests to me they are two different things.

Comment: http://www.cs.ru.nl/~freek/courses/mfocs-2012/risch/1995313.pdf

Comment: Yes, he writes "where $v_0, v_i$ are els of $\mathcal{D}$", on page $169$. Then he also writes $v_0\in \mathcal{D}$ on page $172$, so the two notions coincide, I fear.